# private registry image as docker swarm service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

First of all, to mention I checked multiple questions in Stackoverflow but the requirement was somewhat different or the solution offered was not working in my case, so thought of creating a new question.

1. I am using Local Registry and able to push/pull image from all worker nodes as well
2. Registry service is up and running in all nodes
3. Issue while creating service of local image that I already pushed to the docker.
   Issue: 
   `overall progress: 0 out of 1 tasks
   1/1: ready     [======================================>            ]
   verify: Detected task failure`

Steps I have done:

1. `docker service create --name registry --publish 5000:5000 armbuild/registry`  (mine is raspi so used armbuild)
2. `docker tag XYZImage localhost:5000/XYZImage` -> Working Fine
3. `docker push localhost:5000/XYZImage` -> Working Fine
4. `docker service create --name XYZService --replicas 2 localhost:5000/XYZImage` --> Issue
   Note: Even I tried using IP address and adding that address to insecure registries in daemon.json file.

Any leads? or if I am missing something?

Comment: You should inspect the error because `Detected task failure` is ambiguous. Try to run `docker service logs XYZService` and give me the output

Comment: no logs for that service.

Comment: then don't use "localhost" but the registry's hostname instead.

Comment: fir example: `docker tag XYZImage yourregistry:5000/XYZImage`

Comment: Yes I am using IP Address directly only. I can see all the images under the Local registry from all the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Each container or node is writing to its own volume (/var/lib/registry).  You must use a distributed storage driver if you want to use replicas.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/#use-an-insecure-registry-testing-only):

> The storage back-end you use determines whether you use a fully scaled
>   service or a service with either only a single node or a node
>   constraint.
>
> If you use a distributed storage driver, such as Amazon S3, you can
>   use a fully replicated service. Each worker can write to the storage
>   back-end without causing write conflicts.
>
> If you use a local bind mount or volume, each worker node writes to
>   its own storage location, which means that each registry contains a
>   different data set. You can solve this problem by using a
>   single-replica service and a node constraint to ensure that only a
>   single worker is writing to the bind mount.

Comment: I tried with single and no replica parameters as well, still the same issue.